# Fix commit to broken path

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I made a commit to the default path in my hgrc before I'd updated the path to my new domain. Now, if I then change the path and try to push, it seems as though it's trying to push to the old path (hg complains of some HTML - the same HTML produced by the landing page for my old domain). Any ideas on how I can undo this commit?

Comment: Do you also have a `default-push` path defined in addition to `default`? Can you show the actual message that hg gives you? When you say that you made a commit to the default path, do you mean you made a commit (locally, of course) and then pushed it to the default path? *(You might answer the first as a comment, but please answer the rest (or all) by editing your answer to clarify or add the information.)*

Comment: what is committed has absolutely nothing to do with where it goes.  As others have pointed out only the paths section of a hgrc file or the commandline sets the "what".  Commits handle the "what" and two two are unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial uses one place, and one place only, to determine where to push, and that is the hgrc file in your .hg directory in your repository.

So, to fix this, simply open up the hgrc file in that directory in your favorite text editor and examine the `[paths]` section, since you're allowed to try to push somewhere at all, that section is bound to be there.

In that section you will most likely have the following:

```
[paths]
default = http://olddomain.com/
```

Simply change the url there, and attempt the push again.

Note that there is nothing recorded in the changeset that identifies the place where you intend to push, so there is no need to undo the changeset or otherwise fix it, the information you need to edit is completely separate.